# The tale of Node.js and the https post request

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

In the past few week I was fiddling around with Node.js and Mocha. Happen to bump into a problem which is the following.

I try to test an https post request, but the result is never what I expect.
I can choose from either the test times out, or passes (when it should fail).

Could you please give me some hints/tips what could have gone wrong?

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: "google.com",
  method: "POST"
};


describe("Connection tests", function(){
 it("should return 404", function(done){
  https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    chai.expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(404);
    done(); //if done is here it times out.
  });
      //done - if done is here it returns success instead failure.
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`.end`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback) on the request to finish sending the request (otherwise, Node will wait for more data to be written to it first):

```
https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  chai.expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(404);
  done();
}).end(); // <-- here
```

Comment: [banging head on the keyboard intensifies] Thank you for pointing out my idiotism!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution to the problem:

Instead of https I use request

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var request = require('request');

describe("Connection tests", function(){
 it("is the request approach", function(done){
  request({
   url: "https://www.google.com",
   method: "POST",
   json: true
  }, function(error, response, body){
   console.log(response.statusCode);
   chai.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(405);
   done();
  });
 });
});
```

I know I'm not actually posting anything, a simple GET would be enough, but hey, baby steps!